# How to make React native route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes

So I'm a newbie to React Native so I started a Udemy course to learn it. The course is a bit old so I'm not sure if the code is outdated but point is I was trying to learn how to do routing to change the screen in a simple app but when I click the button, nothing happens. 
App.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Landing from './src/Landing';
import Search from './src/search';

var myBackground = require('./assets/icons/landing.jpg');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentScreen: "landing"
  }
  switchScreen = (currentScreen) => {
    this.setState({currentScreen});
  }
  renderScreen = () =>{
    if(this.state.currentScreen === "landing") {
      return (
        <Landing switchScreen={this.switchScreen }/>
      )
    }
    else if(this.state.currentScreen === "search") {
      return(
        <Search/>
      )
    }
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.renderScreen()}
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0
  },
});
```

The landing component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';

var myBackground = require('../assets/icons/landing.jpg');

class Landing extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } source={myBackground}>
                    <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Welcome to PokeSearch</Text>
                    <Button block={true} style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={()=>this.props.switchScreen("screen")}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start Searching for Pokemon!</Text>
                    </Button>
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0
    },
    imgBackground: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      flex: 1 
  },
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    margin: 10
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'red'
  },
  });


export default Landing;
```

And the search which is very simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Search</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

So when i click the button it should change to the search page but nothing happens. Also i noticed the button doesnt do the flash animation it should when clicked. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working please and thanks in advance!

Comment: onPress={()=>this.props.switchScreen("screen")}  

should be 

onPress={()=>this.props.switchScreen("search")}

Comment: That doesn't work either, I already tried that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build navigation by following this link.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

A typical implementation of navigation is here.

https://github.com/apiko-dev/Perfi/tree/master/app/navigation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried installing navigation the first npm line ran properly but when i tried running expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view 
I got an error saying I should remove  package-lock.json but if i remove that then i get this error: error Couldn't find the binary git

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: You can remove package-lock.json and reinstall packages using `npm i` or ```yarn add```.

Comment: I just tried that and reran the line but i still got the following error: error Couldn't find the binary git
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1

Comment: So i tried creating a fresh app and installing navigation and now it works. So I have no idea what was wrong with my other project....

Comment: would you like to share your previous project?

Comment: Sure but its nothing special just a main window and then a component that I was trying to create a button to access it. When trying to learn to use React Navigation I'm having a bit of trouble though, I was following a YouTube tutorial and he shows how to create a drawer, but I get this error: Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/drawer" from "App.js"
Despite having it imported as such: import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer'